# SpringBoot Did not find handler method, second request onwards

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

One of the endpoints in my application works only the first time I call it, but fails every time afterwards with the error:

**Response:**

```
{
    "timestamp": 1501295150391,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/updates"
}
```

**Logs:**

```
2017-07-28 19:25:50.386 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/updates]
2017-07-28 19:25:50.386 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /updates
2017-07-28 19:25:50.386 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/updates]
2017-07-28 19:25:50.387 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/updates] are [/**]
2017-07-28 19:25:50.387 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/updates] are {}
2017-07-28 19:25:50.388 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/updates] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@74455848]]] and 1 interceptor
2017-07-28 19:25:50.389 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/updates] is: -1
2017-07-28 19:25:50.389 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-07-28 19:25:50.389 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-07-28 19:25:50.390 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2017-07-28 19:25:50.390 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2017-07-28 19:25:50.390 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2017-07-28 19:25:50.390 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2017-07-28 19:25:50.391 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Fri Jul 28 19:25:50 PDT 2017, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available, path=/updates}] as "application/hal+json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@e4487af]
2017-07-28 19:25:50.392 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-07-28 19:25:50.392 DEBUG 76613 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

However, **it works the first time it is called**, with the logs showing:

```
2017-07-28 19:55:41.085 DEBUG 77262 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/updates]
2017-07-28 19:55:41.085 DEBUG 77262 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /updates
2017-07-28 19:55:41.085 DEBUG 77262 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/updates]
2017-07-28 19:55:41.089 DEBUG 77262 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/updates] is: -1
2017-07-28 19:55:41.135 DEBUG 77262 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [PagedResource { content: [Resource { content: hello.update.MatchUpdate@54045f1c, links: [<http://localhost:8080/updates/597ad268c843e7286ab1d059>;rel="self", <http://localhost:8080/updates/597ad268c843e7286ab1d059>;rel="matchUpdate"] }, Resource { content: hello.update.MatchUpdate@48f57e91, links: [<http://localhost:8080/updates/597ad26ac843e7286ab1d05a>;rel="self", <http://localhost:8080/updates/597ad26ac843e7286ab1d05a>;rel="matchUpdate"] }], metadata: Metadata { number: 0, total pages: 1, total elements: 2, size: 30 }, links: [<http://localhost:8080/updates>;rel="self", <http://localhost:8080/profile/updates>;rel="profile", <http://localhost:8080/updates/search>;rel="search"] }] as "application/hal+json" using [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$ResourceSupportHttpMessageConverter@c86b9e3]
2017-07-28 19:55:41.135 DEBUG 77262 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-07-28 19:55:41.136 DEBUG 77262 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

- The Controller is in the top level along with my other controllers, so Spring should be able to locate it
- The Application class is annotated with `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MatchUpdateController.class)` to try and make sure it locates it

**Relevant Files:**

*MatchUpdateRepository:*

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "updates", path = "updates")
public interface MatchUpdateRepository extends MongoRepository<MatchUpdate, String>, MatchUpdateRepositoryCustom {

    List<MatchUpdate> findByReceiverId(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

*MatchUpdateController:*

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class MatchUpdateController {

    private final MatchUpdateRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MatchUpdateController(MatchUpdateRepository repo) {
        repository = repo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updates", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody MatchUpdate update, UriComponentsBuilder builder,
                                    @RequestHeader(value= HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String senderId) {
        if (senderId == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Authorization header required");
        } else {
            return repository.createUpdate(update, senderId, builder);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updates/{id}/accept", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> accept(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody MatchUpdateResponse response,
                                       @RequestHeader(value= HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String senderId) {
        if (response == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Request body cannot be null");
        } else {
            return repository.acceptUpdate(response, id, senderId);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updates/{id}/decline", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> decline(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody MatchUpdateResponse response,
                                        @RequestHeader(value= HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String senderId) {
        if (response == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Request body cannot be null");
        } else {
            return repository.declineUpdate(response, id, senderId);
        }
    }
}
```

*Application:*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MatchUpdateController.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`404` errors occur because of a page not found and in your project controller, it is not mapped with the proper path and you need to correct it. 
you are using a `@RepositoryRestController`, depending on whether you are performing entity-specific actions or not. in this case you need to manually create endpoints. you can refer below to the reference link for `RepositoryRestController` .

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers

you can also use

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/controller")
```

to map the controller path.